# Strange GLSL/Opengl Bug: Multiple sampler

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl

I have a very strange bug. I use multiple textures in a GLSL fragment shader, but I cannot read texture 1 if texture 0 is not set.

**WORKS:**

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texA);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texB);
```

**DOES NOT WORK:**

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texB);
```

In the 2nd example, texB isnt read correctly, but in the first it is. I call this before drawing everything:

```
int samplerAID = mActiveShader->GetUniformID("TexSamplerA");
int samplerBID = mActiveShader->GetUniformID("TexSamplerB");
glUniform1i(samplerAID , 0);
glUniform1i(samplerBID , 1);
```

if I remove all reference to TexSamplerA in the fragment shader, then texB works in example #1

Comment: "I cannot read texture 1 if texture 0 is not set." What happens if you try?

Comment: Did you call `glUseProgram()` **before** the `glUniform1i()` calls? If not, you need to.

Comment: texB is displayed all black, and yes I call glUseProgram (before glUniform) to call my glsl shader, because everything else in the shader works

Comment: I had the same problem and observed that in the same configuration, texture1 reads from unit 0 instead of unit 1 (everything I bind there is displayed).